# Access Spring MVC BindingResult from within a View

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

I'm looking for a way to access a `BindingResult` from within the view (in my case a JSP page).

I have the following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register/accept.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doRegisterAccept(
  @Valid @ModelAttribute("registrationData") RegistrationData registrationData,
  BindingResult bindingResult
) {

  ModelAndView modelAndView         = new ModelAndView();
  modelAndView.addObject("bindingResultXXX", bindingResult);
  modelAndView.setViewName("users/registration/register");
  return modelAndView;

}
```

When executing this, the `RegistrationData` get's populated and the errors are stored in the `BindingResult`. So far, so good. However, I do have to add the `BindingResult` manually into the `ModelAndView` for it to become visible within the View.

Is there a way to **automatically** add the `BindingResult` into the model? I already tried adjusting the method signature to

```
public ModelAndView doRegisterAccept(
  @Valid @ModelAttribute("registrationData") RegistrationData registrationData,
  @ModelAttribute("bindingResult") BindingResult bindingResult
) {
```

where I was hoping - as any other parameter - the `BindingResult` would get added into the model under the key `bindingResult`but unfortunately that's not working.

So, any ideas?

### Addition

I just found that the results indeed get published using the key

```
org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.<NAME_OF_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE>
```

so I suppose just adding it under the plain name is not encouraged by the Spring guys?!

Comment: Interesting question, in some way it should present in view, for instance when displaying validation errors

Answer (score 1):

You have to add "errors" tag in your form view, as described here : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-errorstag.
Then in your Controller, you just put a test :

```
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
   ... display your form page again 
   (and "errors" tags will be populated by validation messages corresponding to each field) ...
}
else {
   ... here, you know that your RegistrationData is valid so you can treat it (save it I guess) ...
}
```